# How to apply StyleSheet to a TextField with plain text

Tags: css, actionscript-3, flash, textfield

Is it possible to apply StyleSheet formatting to a Flash TextField that has only a plain text set either via `text` or `htmlText` properties? In the documentation to the `TextField#styleSheet` property, this example is given:

```
 public class TextStylesheetExample extends Sprite {
    var myLabel:TextField = new TextField();
    var labelText:String = "Hello world.";
    var newStyle:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();

    public function TextStylesheetExample()
    {
        var styleObj:Object = new Object();
        styleObj.fontWeight = "bold";
        styleObj.color = "#660066";
        newStyle.setStyle(".defStyle", styleObj);

        myLabel.styleSheet=newStyle;
        myLabel.htmlText=labelText;
        addChild(myLabel);
    }
}
```

When I run this code in Flash Player 12 / AIR 4, I see only unformatted text. I see some results if the code is changed to something like

```
var labelText:String = "<p>Hello world.</p>";
...
newStyle.setStyle("p", styleObj);
```

I.e., when selectors come to play, it starts working. However, in my usecase, I have just plain texts without any formatting tags and am wondering whether it's possible to style something like `text="Hello World"` with a StyleSheet object. Documentation suggests that it should be but I can't get it working.

Thanks.

Comment: Note: I have also tried "special" selectors like `*` or `global` with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `TextField`, non-HTML text is actually placed within a set of paragraph tags. As an experiment:

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.text = "hello world";
trace(tf.htmlText);
```

The trace output will be:

`<P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Times New Roman" SIZE="12" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">hello world</FONT></P>`

Because there is a nested FONT element that "hardcodes" the styling information, the answer to the original question is **no, plain text TextFields cannot have their font properties styled using a StyleSheet**. Use `defaultTextFormat` or `setTextFormat()` instead.

Comment: `p` was one of the selectors I tried and it didn't work. Your post possibly explains why - there is a "hardcoded" `FONT` tag that overwrites any styles set on `p`. So is the logical conclusion that no, font styles cannot be set on plain text? Or is there a way around it?

Comment: Good point, @Borek. Is there a reason why you're trying to use `StyleSheet` instead of `TextFormat` on plain text?

Comment: Not really, it's just a legacy application that uses stylesheets instead of TextFormat and I was wondering why font styling doesn't work (maybe it used to in the past? I doubt there would be a non-functioning example in the docs)

Comment: In that case, I would suggest using `defaultTextFormat` and `setTextFormat`.